# How to combine a SQLite database with a fragment?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I want to create a molar mass calculator. For this, I need access to my Database where I stored the masses. 
I created a fragment for this. If I click the button, the app should display the mass from the database.

If I put it in an Activity it is working.

This is my DatabaseOpenHelper:

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "molmassen.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

The Access to the Database:

```
public class DatabaseAccess {

    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;
    Cursor c = null;

    public DatabaseAccess(Context context){
        this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);

    }

    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance (Context context){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);

        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void open(){

        this.db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

    public void close(){
        if(db!=null){
            this.db.close();
        }
    }

    public String getMolmasse(String kürzel){
        c=db.rawQuery("select Molmasse from Molmassen where Kürzel = '"+kürzel+"'",new String[]{});
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (c.moveToNext()){
           String masse = c.getString(0);
           buffer.append(""+masse);
        }
        return buffer.toString();

    }
}
```

and the fragment (i guess the problem is there...)

```
public class MolmasseFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
     public DatabaseAccess databaseAccess;

     public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_molmasse, container, false);

        name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        Button query_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.query_button);
        result = view.findViewById(R.id.result);

        databaseAccess = new DatabaseAccess(getActivity());


        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        query_button.setOnClickListener(this);


        return view;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.query_button:


                DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity());
                databaseAccess.open();

                String kürzel = name.getText().toString();
                String masse = databaseAccess.getMolmasse(kürzel);

                result.setText(masse);

                databaseAccess.close();


                break;

            default:
                break;

       }
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/molmassen.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
```

I really hope somebody can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with SQLiteAssetHelper not coping with the introduction of SQLite databases using WAL (write-ahead logging) as the default (journal mode used to be the default until API 28).

If not then, it's basically that the molmassen.file (named exactly that) isn't in the **assets/databases** folder. In either case the fix below will work if the database file is named molmassen.db AND it is in the databases folder of the assets folder.

As such I'd suggest changing to use a non SQLiteAssetHelper method to copy the database.

For example consider the following alternative Database Helper namely **DatabaseOpenHelperAlt**

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelperAlt extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "molmassen.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    Context myContext;
    int buffer_size = 1024 * 4, blocks_copied = 0, bytes_copied = 0;

    public DatabaseOpenHelperAlt(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        myContext = context;
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Error copy database file " + DATABASE_NAME + " - see stack-trace above" );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        /**
         * Does not open the database instead checks to see if the file exists
         * also creates the databases directory if it does not exists
         * (the real reason why the database is opened, which appears to result in issues)
         */

        File db = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath()); //Get the file name of the database
        Log.d("DBPATH","DB Path is " + db.getPath()); //TODO remove for Live App
        if (db.exists()) return true; // If it exists then return doing nothing

        // Get the parent (directory in which the database file would be)
        File dbdir = db.getParentFile();
        // If the directory does not exits then make the directory (and higher level directories)
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            db.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        final String TAG = "COPYDATABASE";

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        Log.d(TAG,"Initiated Copy of the database file " + DATABASE_NAME + " from the assets folder."); //TODO remove for Live App
        //Note how the databases folder is hard coded (to suit the same location as used by SQLiteAssetHelper)
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("databases" + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME); // Open the Asset file
        String dbpath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        Log.d(TAG,"Asset file " + DATABASE_NAME + " found so attmepting to copy to " + dbpath); //TODO remove for Live App

        // Path to the just created empty db
        //String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        File outfile = new File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString());
        Log.d("DBPATH","path is " + outfile.getPath()); //TODO remove for Live App
        //outfile.setWritable(true); // NOT NEEDED as permission already applies
        //OutputStream myoutputx2 = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        /* Note done in checkDatabase method
        if (!outfile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        */

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
            blocks_copied++;
            Log.d(TAG,"Ateempting copy of block " + String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " which has " + String.valueOf(length) + " bytes."); //TODO remove for Live App
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            bytes_copied += length;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Finished copying Database " + DATABASE_NAME +
                        " from the assets folder, to  " + dbpath +
                        String.valueOf(bytes_copied) + "were copied, in " +
                        String.valueOf(blocks_copied) + " blocks of size " +
                        String.valueOf(buffer_size) + "."
        ); //TODO remove for Live App
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        Log.d(TAG,"All Streams have been flushed and closed."); //TODO remove for Live App
    }
}
```

Using the above along with an amended DatabaseAccess class (to invoke the alternative DatabaseHelper and also method for getting the underlying SQLiteDatabase for testing without having to have an exact same database as yours) **check the comments** :-

```
public class DatabaseAccess {

    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;
    Cursor c = null;

    public DatabaseAccess(Context context){
        //this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context); //<<<<<<<<<< OLD REPLACED
        this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelperAlt(context); //<<<<<<<<<< NEW
        db = this.openHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<<< force open
    }

    //!!!!!!!!! ADDED for simple testing
    public SQLiteDatabase getDB() {
        return db;
    }

    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance (Context context){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);

        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void open(){

        this.db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
        if(db!=null){
            this.db.close();
        }
    }

    public String getMolmasse(String kürzel){
        c=db.rawQuery("select Molmasse from Molmassen where Kürzel = '"+kürzel+"'",new String[]{});
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            String masse = c.getString(0);
            buffer.append(""+masse);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

The running App with the following in the fragment (reduced for convenience) :-

```
public class MolassesFragment extends Fragment {

    public DatabaseAccess databaseAccess;

    private MolassesViewModel mViewModel;

    public static MolassesFragment newInstance() {
        return new MolassesFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.molasses_fragment, container, false);
        databaseAccess = new DatabaseAccess(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseAccess.getDB();
        Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MolassesViewModel.class);
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }
}
```

The for the first run (the run that copies the database), it works and the log shows :-

```
2019-03-26 12:14:15.419 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample D/DBPATH: DB Path is /data/user/0/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample/databases/molmassen.db
2019-03-26 12:14:15.419 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample D/COPYDATABASE: Initiated Copy of the database file molmassen.db from the assets folder.
2019-03-26 12:14:15.419 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample D/COPYDATABASE: Asset file molmassen.db found so attmepting to copy to /data/user/0/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample/databases/molmassen.db
2019-03-26 12:14:15.419 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample D/DBPATH: path is /data/user/0/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample/databases/molmassen.db
2019-03-26 12:14:15.419 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 1 which has 4096 bytes.
2019-03-26 12:14:15.420 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 2 which has 4096 bytes.
.....
2019-03-26 12:14:15.422 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample D/COPYDATABASE: Ateempting copy of block 27 which has 4096 bytes.
2019-03-26 12:14:15.422 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample D/COPYDATABASE: Finished copying Database molmassen.db from the assets folder, to  /data/user/0/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample/databases/molmassen.db110592were copied, in 27 blocks of size 4096.
2019-03-26 12:14:15.423 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample D/COPYDATABASE: All Streams have been flushed and closed.
2019-03-26 12:14:15.452 7929-7929/aaa.so55342826preexistdbassethelperexample
```

.......... rest of log omitted as too large, but suffice to say the expected tables were display.

Comment: Thanks a lot :), nevertheless I fixed it on my own. I do not know what the problem was. I ran the App on another computer - suddenly it worked... After trying it on my own computer again, it still keeps working.